# How to keep adding to your values (int) in java?

Tags: java, variables, int

i'm having trouble understanding and probably remembering how you keep adding to a field/variable. I want it to remember my last input and add it to the total of the int value. So the total keeps going up each time I input a new number.

i got 2 other class that just containing Getter/Setter and a Construtor

```
public class foo {
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static int input;
    static A a = new A(10);
    static B b = new B(10);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (1 != 2) {  
            keepValue();
        }         
    }

    public static void keepValue() {
        a.setI(scan.nextInt());
        int sum = a.getI() + b.getJ();
        System.out.println("the sum of the two numbers is: "+sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use inane statement like `while(1 != 2)`. Use `while(true)` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps `a.setI(a.getI() + scan.nextInt())`